# Insert with openrowset into SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, openrowset

I'm trying to save data from a `.xlsx` file into a table, however I should be able to return errors for each row that could not be inserted.

The `.xlsx` file and table has this structure

```
ID | NAME | LAST_NAME | AGE
```

What I need to do is return errors of type

> "ERROR ON ROW 3, COLUMN 'AGE' CAN NOT BE NULL".

What should be the right approach to do this using openrowset as function to read the file?

Comment: You need to develop a validation framework for your data.  There are lots of ways to do that, it just depends on how you want to process the data, when you want to see those messages, if you want to see all messages at the same time, etc.

Comment: You can either change your table to allow nulls, or load this into a #TempTable first and change the NULL's to a blank space or something similar.